# Create symlink to a symlink without following

Tags: java, groovy, nio

I am trying to create a symbolic link (A) to another symbolic link (B) which point to an actual file (C):

A -> B -> C

I am using the standard java 7 NIO.2 code:

```
Path sourceFilePath      = ...
Path destinationFilePath = ...

destinationFile.parentFile.mkdirs()

Files.createSymbolicLink(symlinkFilePath, targetFilePath)
```

However **the NIO.2 API is automatically following the symlinks**, which is not what I want.

Is there any other way of the NIO.2 or any other Java/Groovy library to do so?

Comment: Try using the Files.setAttribute on path with option NOFOLLOW_LINKS.

Comment: Quoting Javadocs: " By default, symbolic links are followed and the file attribute of the final target of the link is set. If the option NOFOLLOW_LINKS is present then symbolic links are not followed."

Comment: It does not work. Can you provide a sample code?

Comment: If you're seeing this, then it might be OS, file-system or java version specific. I tried the straightforward creation of symlinks without options and got A -> B -> C. I'm on ubuntu 16.04, ext4 filesystem, java 8u121. Path objects were created with the File.toPath() method. Can post the code if you're interested.